# How to add 2 elements in a list and put the summation of each 2 elements into another list

Tags: python-2.7, list, nested-lists

I'm trying to make user input num_list then create sum_list to add up every 2 elements in num_list into a new list

```
sum_list[0] = num_list[0]
sum_list[1] = num_list[0] + num_list[1]
```

and so on

I tried creating sum_list initially with num_list[0] then add n elements to it from num_list

```
n = int(input('Enter number of elements : ')) 



for num in range(0, n): 
    element = float(input('Enter your elements: ')) 
    num_list.append(element) 

sum_list = num_list[0]

for number in range(len(num_list)):
    sum_list[0:n] = sum_list + num_list[n]
```

However, when I executed the program, I got IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
n = int(input('Enter number of elements : ')) 

num_list = []
for num in range(0, n): 
    element = float(input('Enter your elements: ')) 
    num_list.append(element) 

sum_list = [num_list[0]]

for idx, number in enumerate(num_list[1:], 1):
    sum_list.append(number + num_list[idx-1])
print(sum_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through `num_list` until the second last element, and add consecutive elements as you loop.

```
sum_list=[num_list[0]]

for i in range(len(num_list)-1):
    sum_list.append(num_list[i]+num_list[i+1])
```